# Dreamweaver javascript code hints

Tags: javascript, intellisense, dreamweaver

I'd to use DW cs 4 but before to buy I want to test javascript code hints.

However that feature doesn't work at all.

I have an external .js library and then into an html file I load it
but when I type functions or object by name nothing happen.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the answer you want to hear, but I'd suggest editing your Javascript in a separate editor. I'd recommend the free [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com), which is what I use for editing HTML and CSS as well. I own Adobe CS4 Web Premium, which includes Dreamweaver, but frankly speaking, I never use Dreamweaver at all. It is not designed for intense Javascript, but expects that you will adopt its model of adding "behaviors" to your page through a dumbed-down interface.

If you need to rely on a WYSIWYG HTML editor to get layout done, you can still edit your Javascript separately. Use Dreamweaver and your JS editor side-by-side. But let me warn you that certain layout options and dynamic HTML creation will be either very difficult or simply closed to you. This failing is not unique to Dreamweaver, but exists for all WYSIWYG editors. As soon as you surrender your markup and CSS generation to one of them, not to mention your Javascript coding, you lose certain abilities.

Comment: I just downloaded and it seems good. However the intellisense also not work when in a .js file I try to use object of another .js file.
Can I do that?

Comment: Oh, you want Javascript intellisense to understand your coding *outside* a particular page, as if it were part of an entire framework? I'm afraid it doesn't work that way. Flex works like that (which is a very cool feature), but nothing else is going to understand your class hierarchy outside of what is represented on the page you are editing.

Comment: Well I did this: Menu Edit->Preferences then Languages|Javascript and then Javascript Directory to add direcory where there are the .js files I need and so the IDE scan for that dirs and so the intellisense works! One point however: I restarted the IDE...